# Update SwipeRefreshLayout from a Service?

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a SwipeRefreshLayout. I have a Service too. While the service is working, the RefreshLayout should show itself refreshing, and after the service finished running, the Service turns of the refreshing.

How can I do this? I don't have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Service starts Running, you can send a broadcast to show Refreshlayout itself refreshing; and when the Service stops Running(onDestroy), you can send a broadcast to finish refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

When your service stops running stop the refreshe icon `swipeRefresher.setRefreshing(false);`